# Mobile Responsiveness Issue on Service Portal: Resolution Scaling

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, servicenow

Hello Developer Community,

I'm reaching out with a concern related to mobile responsiveness on our service portal.

We have designed our portal to be responsive for a mobile scope of 360x767 using the CSS.

We've tailored our portal to be mobile-responsive within a specific range, and everything looks fine on a standard 100% windows resolution, as shown in the attached screenshot. However, when the resolution is adjusted to 150% (a recommended setting for some Windows environments), certain elements are misaligned. For example, the right corner global header, which should ideally remain hidden within our targeted resolution range, becomes visible.

Given my limited expertise in mobile responsiveness, I'm unsure of the best way forward:

Should we make design alterations to cater to a 150% resolution scaling?
Or would it be more prudent to advise our clients to keep their windows resolution at 100% for the best portal experience?
Any guidance or suggestions from this community would be immensely valuable. Thank you for taking the time to assist.

Thanks,
Roque

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.